# EditText not adding points to full score for Quiz App

Tags: java, android

In my quiz app I get points for my buttons and checkboxes, but the edittext questions aren't being counted when they are correct. Here's my java code for one edittext field:

```js
EditText question2_answer = findViewById(R.id.question2_answer);
        if (question2_answer.equals("Surrounding membrane, Cytoplasm and Nucleus")) {
            question2_score = 1;
        } else {
            question2_score = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use getText().toString() so you can get entered text in the EditText

```
EditText question2_answer = findViewById(R.id.question2_answer);
            if (question2_answer.getText().toString().equals("Surrounding membrane, Cytoplasm and Nucleus")) {
                question2_score = 1;
            } else {
                question2_score = 0;
            }
```